# how to write a web service with soap

Tags: java, tomcat, soap

I have a web service (client-server) written in java. With help of that user can upload a file and generate another output file. Now I want to do the same thing with soap(i mean server - server).But I have no idea how can I do that. Can someone help me to find some useful links, tutorials or examples how build web service with soap and how to write script to merge it with my java class. I am using tomcat server.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: @Vardes

Can you clarify what you mean by

web service (client-server)

and

soap(i mean server - server)

I would want clarity on what technology you used in the former - for example, Javascript/AJAX for client and Java for server. Similar explanation for the server-server scenario would also help.

Answer (score 1):

http://oreilly.com/catalog/progwebsoap/chapter/ch03.html

there they show how to write and use SOAP Web Services. A little further down on that page there is a section "Creating Web Services in Java with Apache SOAP". Maybe this helps a bit.

Greetings
Daniel